# Google Images: can't select different image sizes

Tags: google-search, google-image-search

For a while back, when you performed a search on Google Images, you could click on the image dimensions (for example `350x200`) and then it will display all image sizes of *that* image.

Since the recent update of Google Images, this option doesn't seem to be present any more.

Did they hide it?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that if you drag the image in question to the search bar, you can get to "all sizes" that way:[image]

Comment: This no longer works in 2022. It seems -- from my experience, not from reading anything official -- that Google has killed that feature